# Accessing an Image outside of a jar from inside a jar

Tags: java, file, jar, path

I tried searching for similar answers but I'm still facing a few difficulties. I'm trying to access a .gif from inside a jar. My file structure is:

```
src
  |-> main
         |->webapp
                  |->images
                          |-> bulb.gif
                  |->signed.jar
```

If I use an absolute file path then I can grab my image by just using `return (new ImageIcon(path, description)).getImage();` but I'm trying to just use relative paths. I tried using `return (new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/bulb.gif"))).getImage();` but that didn't work. Am I using the correct pathway in the latter method, or is there a better alternative?

EDIT: I also tried below with no success.

```
 InputStream image = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/bulb.gif");
            Image in = null;
            try {
                in = ImageIO.read(image); 
            }
            catch(Exception e){ 
            }

            return (new ImageIcon(in, description)).getImage();
```

My file structure is pertaining to the question is

```
project/src/main/java/web/load/jar/something.java
project/src/main/java/web/load/jar/images/bulb.gif
project/build.xml
project/target/thing.signed.jar
```

for my jar and

```
mainproject/src/main/app/thing.signed.jar
mainproject/src/main/app/images/bulb.gif
```

for my main webapp. I was trying to access bulb.gif from my signed.jar but it might be easier to just put it in my signed.jar.

Comment: If it's not in the jar you can't get it as a resource unless it's also on the classpath.

Comment: Did you tried **getResourceAsStream** ?

Comment: @DaveNewton would I be able to access the image If I put it inside the jar?

Comment: Sure. But you can access it as a regular file, too, you just have to have the path be actually correct.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think determining the path is my main problem. I have a few projects in my workspace (on eclipse) but I posted the two in my question. How would I need to rework my path if I wanted to access the image either inside or outside the jar?